# From momemtum Hamiltonian to real space Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, field-theory, fourier-transform, topological-insulators

I know how to calculate a bulk momentum space Hamiltonian from a real space one. For example, given a SSH model $$H=v\sum_ic^\dagger_{iB}c_{iA}+w\sum_ic^\dagger_{i+1,A}c_{iB}+h.c.,$$ its bulk momentum-space Hamiltonian is $$H(k)=\left(\begin{matrix}0&v+we^{-ik}\\v+we^{ik}&0\end{matrix}\right).$$ How do I implement inverse Fourier transform to gain the real-space Hamiltonian?

Comment: you write that you are familiar with FT from position to momentum space, so the inverse should be quite straight forward. Can you elaborate? is your problem with how to do the inverse FT in general or specifically in the case where $H(k)$ is given in matrix form?

Answer (score 2):

The momentum space Hamiltonian you have written down is the full Hamiltonian in the sector of the Hilbert space indexed by the quantum number called the (crystal) momentum. It is a 2x2 matrix because, once we specify the momentum $k$, we still need to specify which sublattice $\sigma$ we are in. Therefore, our full Hamiltonian can be expressed as:
$$H = \sum_k \sum_{\sigma \sigma'} H_{\sigma, \sigma'}(k) c_{k, \sigma}^{\dagger}c_{k, \sigma'}$$
where $\sigma, \sigma' \in \{ A, B \}$ is the sublattice index. Now, to go back to real space, we simply need to write our $c_k$'s in terms of $c_i$'s as:
$$c_{k, \sigma}^{\dagger} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_k e^{ik\sigma} e^{ikx}c_x^{\dagger}$$
which, when substituted back into the full Hamiltonian yields the SSH Hamiltonian in real space!